# What are the benefits of your server having a static IP address?

Tags: ip-address, static-ip-address

I understand that it may be useful if your server makes requests and the receivers of the requests have an IP whitelist, and because it means that if someone knows your IP address won't change they don't have to do a DNS lookup to find it. What other benefits are there?

Answer (score 0):

Alot of the main reasons I know have everything to do with DNS. If you go to a `website.com` that Domain name must be translated to an IP address. If it's static, that's a simple lookup. If it's constantly changing than you add in a layer of instability by bringing in a DDNS service to check the external IP, and update the DNS record accordingly. In addition, I have encountered several API services, namely Google, that require a whitelisted IP to your server (That one in particular was impossible to work around as we were on a shared server at the time with a dynamic IP). I've also heard of other configuration portals, such as AWS, that may require whitelisted IPs to gain access. There's also the SSH terminal which is always wise to leave disabled if your not using it, but if you are only allowing connections by a whitelist of IPs is a great idea.

From a networking perspective, it provides an easier setup experience and easier troubleshooting. Knowing that a server will always be at `n.n.n.n` can help a lot when working through issues. In addition, having static IPs on a network could increase security by adding a small layer of obscurity, and accountability as each IP address would be know cataloged device. I have personally encountered a few networks that require your Mac Address to be Registered with IT in order to given a static IP address, and get on the network (A giant pain if you don't already have internet, or can't figure out the MAC address of the device). There are also numerous services that may require themselves to be hard coded to a specific IP. If you have to connect a client to a server on the complete opposite end of a routed network, having that IP never change is practically required.

Overall though I would say that for many specific purposes **it just makes things easier.**